# RecyclerView with a single CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I would like to achieve the following effect:

[image]

It's basically a list that resides in a single CardView. Since it's a single card, it slides up and down making it look nice. It is easily achieveable using a ScrollView and a LinearLayout. But that solution would have performance issues when there are a lot of elements in the list since the views of all the elements would be in memory. Is there a way to achieve this using a RecyclerView?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how about wrapping a RecyclerView inside a CardView (my direct thought, i didn't try out)

Comment: one of another trick I could think of is to set the viewtype for first and last item, so they use different view holders

Comment: That would make the card static, and the top and bottom wouldn't slide off the edge off the screen

Comment: i think i could imagine the issue with cardview. try my second comment with a custom viewholder :D (not a cardview, but a half-card style background viewholder)

Comment: @MikeM. the recycler view has rounded corner on top and bottom, that's what he wants :D

Comment: Since in a recyclreview, there would be a card for each items, it would produce some visual artifacts like overlapping shadows (I think)

Comment: @Longi You don't have to use CardViews for RecyclerView items. You can use regular old ViewGroups, like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.

Comment: @Mike M. Though it can be done with drawables with rounded corners and shadow drawables, it sounds like a lot of work (especially creating proper shadows)

Comment: @Longi We must be seeing different images, 'cause I don't see any rounded corners in the gif. (I don't see any shadows, either, but that could be image quality.) Each element, to me, looks like a plain LinearLayout with a TextView in it.

Comment: @Mike M. Right, the gif is pretty low res. What I want is make the list look like one really tall CardView. Like a piece of paper that slides up/down

Answer (score 0):

I tried that with item decorations, and it works. It's basically the adapted code from a cardview itself and how it draws it's shadow.

[CardViewDecoration Source](https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bleeding182/recyclerviewdecorations/CardViewDecoration.java)

The example below uses some additional decorations (margin, separatos and header background) but this is like it could look, withoud using any additional views or layouts.

[image: This is how it looks]

Answer (score 0):

For those who's looking for a solution to achieve this effect, you can simply create a CardView and set its properties(Card's elevation, Background, UseCompatPadding...) to your RecyclerView. something like this:

```
private void init() {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
        new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    setCardViewBackgroundToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        data.add("Item " + i);
    }
    adapter = new TestAdapter(data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setCardViewBackgroundToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
    cardView.setUseCompatPadding(true);
    cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
    int cardShadow = (int) cardView.getCardElevation();
    recyclerView.setPadding(cardView.getContentPaddingLeft() + cardShadow,
        cardView.getContentPaddingTop() + cardShadow + 3,
        cardView.getContentPaddingRight() + cardShadow,
        cardView.getContentPaddingBottom() + cardShadow + 3);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(recyclerView, cardView.getCardElevation());
    recyclerView.setBackground(cardView.getBackground());
}
```

result:
[image]